# Cobra/LDTP imports not working

Tags: python, automated-tests

I'm trying to set up Cobra/LDTP on windows. I've run the installer binary, and am trying to follow the tutorials

when I add

```
from ldtp import *
from ldtputils import *
```

My script chokes because I apparently don't have the modules installed. The Tutorials are very Linux-centric, which is fine (I'm going to have to run tests there anyway), but Windows is our primary platform.

I've had a look through the tutorial and the only instruction is "Run the binary"

A little help would be much appreciated.

Allen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can share what I have done to setup ldtp on windows.

1. Download CorbaWinLDTP from this [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cobra-winldtp/downloads). Select the msi based on
   your operating system.
2. Install the CobraWinLDTP-X.X.X.msi msi.
3. Install python from this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/). I used Python 2.7.11 based on
   project requirement.
4. Open Command line by run->cmd instruction.
5. If the python install location is "c:\Python27" navigate to that
   folder. if "Python" path is registered in path variable then you can
   ignore this step.
6. Type python in the command line.
7. You will see ">>", informing you that you are in python REPL.
8. Type in `from ldtp import *` and check whether you are able to
   import ldtp or not. if you reach to ">>" without any error. You are
   all set to use ldtp commands (most simplest `getwindowlist()`) from
   REPL.

[image]

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with linux. Just write your script with import ldtp module statement and use it methods even your IDE says they not found. Run /usr/bin/ldtp from console, then run your script.